# It is possible to have a null params in c#, but why?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does params behave like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210519/why-does-params-behave-like-this)

If you write a method like this:

`void TestMethod(params object[] args) 
{
}`

then if you call it like this: TestMethod() then the array will be empty.

and if you call it like this: TestMethod(null, null) then the array will be an array with two null values.

but why, when you call the method like this: TestMethod(null) will the array be null?

I would have expected the result to be an array with one null value.

I know about this [C# - Is it possible to have null params?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584131/c-is-it-possible-to-have-null-params) but does not explain why.

--Edit:

It's also interesting that TestMethod((object)null) is an array with one null value
and TestMetod((object[])null) is a null array.

It's just a case where being explicit in your intentions, by casting null to your expected type is the right way to go.

Comment: That is kind of interesting, given [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) states that a single argument should be the first element in the params array. one would expect `(params) = object[]{ null }` not `(params) = null`.

Comment: Maybe this is the answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210519/why-does-params-behave-like-this

Comment: There's a difference between whether a reference IS null (e.g. "TestMethod (null)"), whether the object being referred to CONTAINS nulls or whether the object is merely "empty".  Here's a good link on "parameter arrays":  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645765%28v=vs.71%29.aspx  And yes, it is possible for a function to pass "null" as a parameter.

Comment: @Daniel T, that's a good link, and is the correct answer in my opinion.'